# Using a Date filtered value from a SubForm on the MainForm

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subform

I am trying to get the last entry of an allready filtered SubForm and place that single value on the MainForm. The entry should also be between a Date_0 and Date_1 alltough Date_1 is not allways specified (in that case simply get the last entry from the SubForm). So you get a more graphical idea (this is a simplification of the real Form):

**MainForm:**

| Date_0 | Date_1 | ValueToGet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/12/23 | 2021/02/27 | *Value from Subform* |

**SubForm:**

| Dates | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/12/20 | 1200 |
| 2020/12/23 | 1189 |
| 2021/01/25 | 1173 |
| *2021/02/20* | *1165* |
| 2021/03/12 | 1333 |

The value to collect from the SubForm would be, in this example, the fourth entry (between Date_0 and Date_1, and last entry in that Date range). The value is then stored in a txtBox in the MainForm as the Form Loads. I know the solution is probably setting a SQL filter on the txtBox, but I do not know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deleted my answer because I did not fully read question and then I tested my suggestion and aggregate function won't work with reference to textboxes for dynamic parameter. This will most likely require Domain Aggregate function or VBA custom function. Still exploring.

Comment: You may need some VBA coding and to invoke codes by clicking a command button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below sub-

```
Private Sub cmdGetResult_Click()
Dim strFilter As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Me.Refresh
    
    strFilter = "[Dates] BETWEEN #" & Me.Date_0 & "# AND #" & Me.Date_1 & "#"

    Forms![Form1]![subformTest].Form.Filter = strFilter
    Forms![Form1]![subformTest].Form.FilterOn = True
    
    Set rs = Me.subformTest.Form.RecordsetClone
    
    rs.MoveLast
    Me.txtValueToGet = rs!values
    
    Forms![Form1]![subformTest].Form.FilterOn = False
    Set rs = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The button works on my example (with a NZ() function on date_1 in case of Null), but problem is, the subForm has allready a set filter and when modifying it the records get messed up. Could I somehow apply the filter directly on the DAO.Recordset without filtering the actual subForm's recordset?

Answer (score 0):

The *OnLoad* event may be too early, but something like this should work:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Value   As Long
    Dim Found   As Boolean

    Set Records = Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone
    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.FindFirst "[Dates] >= #" & Format(Me!Date_0.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        If Records.NoMatch Then
            ' No dates to look up.
        Else
            If IsNull(Me!Date_1.Value) Then
                Records.MoveLast
                Value = Records!Values.Value
                Found = True
            Else
                While Records.EOF = False And Found = False
                    If Records!Dates.Value >= Me!Date_1.Value Then
                        Value = Records!Values.Value
                        Found = True
                    End If
                    Records.MoveNext
                Wend
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Records.Close

    If Found = True Then
        Me!ValueToGet.Value = Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. While running the code, in the case of Date_1 beign Null, i get following error: `Value = Records!Values.Value <Item not found in the collection.>` Any idea why this happens?

Comment: That is weird. There should be a record, but double-check everything.